# avahi_entry_group_new() failed: Too many objects

Tags: django, apache, mercurial, django-rest-framework, avahi

I'm working on making a REST API for my research lab's database. I'm using the Django REST framework and I've gotten everything running smoothly on my local machine. All my code is in its own branch in our Mercurial repo. When I switch branches on our server, the website crashes with:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

The error logs on our server look like this:

```
[Tue Feb 03 12:55:56 2015] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Feb 03 12:55:56 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Feb 03 12:55:56 2015] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Feb 03 12:55:56 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_wsgi/3.2 Python/2.6.6 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 03 12:56:11 2015] [error] avahi_entry_group_add_service_strlst("Lee on [server name]") failed: Local name collision
(this sort of error repeats many times)
[Tue Feb 03 12:56:13 2015] [error] avahi_entry_group_new() failed: Too many objects
(this error repeats many times.)
```

I've tried Googling the avahi errors to no avail. Anyone have any insight?

Because of the "too many objects" part of the error, I thought that it might somehow be related to not setting the pagination settings for the API. I only have a couple test objects on my local dev version of the database, but the actual database has tens of thousands. I set up pagination and tried again but it didn't change anything.

Comment: It is possible that the culprit might be an out of data avahi version. (https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=557931) Checking that out now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the culprit was not having the djangorestframework package installed for the correct version of Python on the server!? Hopefully this helps someone later down the line.